# Triggering colorbox on page load using href and rel properties results in empty colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using ColorBox to let readers view and navigate through a series of divs that are in the page -- a mixed media slideshow, more or less. I am using this script, and you can view the page functionality at http://new.evideoexpress.com/services/.

```
jQuery(".colorbox").colorbox({
   inline:true,
   rel:'colorbox',
   transition:"elastic",
   width:"75%",
   height:"75%",
   current:"",
   previous:"Previous",
   next:"Next",
   close: "Close"
});
```

I use the rel property to create the group of divs for my gallery, each of which is also assigned an ID. The anchors in the document that trigger the lightbox look like this:

```
<a class="colorbox" href="#commercial-distribution"><span>Learn More</span></a>
```

This all works as expected. But under certain conditions, I also want to trigger the colorbox when the page loads. So as a test, I am running this script when the document is ready, using the href property to identify the target div.

```
jQuery.colorbox({
   href:"#commercial-distribution",
   inline:true,
   rel:'colorbox',
   transition:"elastic",
   width:"75%",
   height:"75%",
   current:"",
   previous:"Previous",
   next:"Next",
   close: "Close"
});
```

From what I've read, my expectation is that running this script as the page loads is the equivalent of running the first script when a.colorbox is clicked. However, though the colorbox opens after the page loads, but it is empty, without any contents.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be appreciated.